# How do you format and pass the date for better interoperable compatibility?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, soa

In our production environment of 12 servers we have an issue with the code

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("Thu, 10 Mar 2011 13:15:33 GMT");
```

and this is not all the time and just on few of the servers (once per month maybe) it will throw the

```
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String, DateTimeFormatInfo, DateTimeStyles)
```

The date "Thu, 10 Mar 2011 13:15:33 GMT" is a real example for today it originates from another environment and is created in the following way

```
string.Format("{0:R}", ExpiresOn.ToUniversalTime())
```

The second day we plug servers back in the farm and they will continue to work fine.

- There is any way to avoid this ?
- Because this information is opaque for the consumers we think switching to ticks is this better ?
- Any good practices ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the relation to SOA? How is this formatted date being "passed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. This is a rule. Use it for parsing of Dates, of numbers (especially floats/doubles/decimals), for ToString(ing) Dates, numbers (especially floats/doubles/decimals) etc. And if you handle date, always think if it would be better to handle them in UTC or in your local timezone. If you have to handle coordination between servers/persons in multiple timezones, always use (store) UTC dates.

Comment: +1. Basically the poster thought this way to format soething is correct worldwide. InvariantCulture is exactly done for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is with what I came up according to previous answer

```
var original = DateTime.Now;
var stringified = original.ToString("r",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and on the consumer side/server

```
var restored = DateTime.ParseExact(stringified, "r", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

We did some testing and so far it looks good.
If you feel like I'm wrong or it can be done simpler let me know thanks.

Comment: Technically this is overkill... "r" (like "o" and "s") are "fixed" formats, equal in all the cultures. If you look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/az4se3k1.aspx you'll see that other formats have examples for various cultures, but the "r", "o", "s" formats have a single example. I'll add that, if you have to pass arround dates as strings, I would choose a "compact not redundant" format (so one without the weekday), like "o" OR a very simple/basic format (like "G", 03/12/2011 21:08:07 dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm:ss). The last is very basic and very easy to parse by other language